# meshgrid matlab to c++ different results

Tags: c++, matlab

[image]
here is the matlab code i'm trying to convert to c++
where

size(Iorig) ==   1334X 2026

```
%% label checkers
Label = zeros(size(Iorig));
Margins = 11;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(Iorig,2),1:size(Iorig,1));
k = 1;
for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:6
        rr = rect{i,j};
        x1 = rr(1);
        x2 = rr(1) + rr(3);
        y1 = rr(2);
        y2 = rr(2) + rr(4);
        Label(X>=x1+Margins&X<x2-Margins&Y>=y1+Margins&Y<y2-Margins) = k;
        k = k+1;
    end
end
```

I understand that we want to label the rectangles which are found in the previous step, there are 24 of those.
but I don't understand how to convert this line into easy c++ code without allocating a huge buffer of X and Y which basically just holds... indices..
thanks for your help here is what i started doing.

```
    //label Checkers
List<List<int>^>^ label = gcnew List<List<int>^>();
    int margins = 11;
    int k = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            MacbethCheckerBatchesColor^ rect = autoDetectMacbethResult[i * 6 + j];
            Point^ r = rect->Points[0];
            int x1 = r->X;
            int y1 = r->Y;
            r = rect->Points[2];
            int x2 = r->X;
            int y2 = r->Y;

            for (int h = 0; h < inputImage->HeightLines; h++)
            {
                List<int>^ tempRow = gcnew List<int>();
                for (int w = 0; w < inputImage->WidthColumns; w++)                    
                {
                    if ( (w>= x1+margins) & (w<x2-margins) & (h >= y1+margins) & (h<y2-margins) )
                    {
                        tempRow->Add(k);                            
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        tempRow->Add(0);
                    }
                }
                label->Add(tempRow);
            }
            k= k+100;//i tried here many other numbers... same result
        }
    }
```

Here is my result can you please help me find my mistake, the rectangles are the same, I guesss I have some other logical mistake.

[image]

Comment: This line creates a logical array: `X>=x1+Margins&X<x2-Margins&Y>=y1+Margins&Y<y2-Margins`. You can replace that with an `if`-statement that does `floor`/`ceil` inside a nested `for`-loop.

Comment: does it mean I need to run on all of the image size every time? what about the different indices for Y and X?

Comment: You can loop over the correct indices using the condition of the for loop instead of generating arrays with those indices. This would produce a quadruple nested for loop, but that's basically what vectorization does for you under the hood anyway.

Comment: @MadPhysicist please see my update. I'm still missing something here